# This can definitely be shorter but I'm a noob

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to not have to reinstate the print over and over. Not sure how to create a function for this process though because c1 through c4 change position with each if statement. My question is specificaly how do I implimint this code and make it smaller, as I plan on adding in even more classes to this list up to perhaps 15-20.

```
if c1 == M1:
    print("\n")
    print("Monday 1", c1)
    print("Monday 2", c2)
    print("Tuesday 1", c3)
    print("Tuesday 2", c4)
    counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
elif c1 == M2:
    print("\n")
    print("Monday 1", c4)
    print("Monday 2", c1)
    print("Tuesday 1", c2)
    print("Tuesday 2", c3)
    counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
elif c1 == T1:
    print("\n")
    print("Monday 1", c3)
    print("Monday 2", c4)
    print("Tuesday 1", c1)
    print("Tuesday 2", c2)
    counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
elif c1 == T2:
    print("\n")
    print("Monday 1", c2)
    print("Monday 2", c3)
    print("Tuesday 1", c4)
    print("Tuesday 2", c1)
    counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

This is the Full Code that was requested as I'm unable to brute force the answer.

```
#All the students and their avalable days/times
students = ("Alec", "M1", "T1"), ("Ben", "M1", "M2", "T1"), ("Carl", "M1", "T1"), ("David", "M1", "M2", "T1"), ("Elvis", "M1", "M2", "T1", "T2"),\
           ("Fiona", "M1", "M2", "T1", "T2"), ("Gage", "M1", "M2", "T2"), ("Henry", "T1", "T2"), ("Isabel", "T2"), ("Jack", "T2")


#All classes
M1 = []
M2 = []
T1 = []
T2 = []

#Lessons the need for multiple lines of repeated code
def add_student(class_name, classes):
    if class_name in student:
        classes.append(student[0])

#Checks if class has minimum of 4 students
def counting(c1, c2, c3, c4):
        count = 0
        if len(c1) >= 4:
            count += len(c1)
        if len(c2) >= 4:
            count += len(c2)
        if len(c3) >= 4:
            count += len(c3)
        if len(c4) >= 4:
            count += len(c4)
        print("{:,}".format(count * 50000), "VND")


def first_sort(a, b, c, d):
    c1 = a.copy()
    c2 = b.copy()
    c3 = c.copy()
    c4 = d.copy()
    all_classes = (c1, c2, c3, c4)
    remove = []

    for student in students:
        for i in all_classes:
            if student[0] in remove:
                try:
                    i.remove(student[0])
                except:
                    pass
            elif student[0] in i:
                remove.append(student[0])

    if c1 == M1:
        print("\n")
        print("Monday 1", c1)
        print("Monday 2", c2)
        print("Tuesday 1", c3)
        print("Tuesday 2", c4)
        counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
    elif c1 == M2:
        print("\n")
        print("Monday 1", c4)
        print("Monday 2", c1)
        print("Tuesday 1", c2)
        print("Tuesday 2", c3)
        counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
    elif c1 == T1:
        print("\n")
        print("Monday 1", c3)
        print("Monday 2", c4)
        print("Tuesday 1", c1)
        print("Tuesday 2", c2)
        counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)
    elif c1 == T2:
        print("\n")
        print("Monday 1", c2)
        print("Monday 2", c3)
        print("Tuesday 1", c4)
        print("Tuesday 2", c1)
        counting(c1, c2, c3, c4)


#Checks if all the students are in a class then adds those who are into the class
for student in students:
    add_student("M1", M1)
    add_student("M2", M2)
    add_student("T1", T1)
    add_student("T2", T2)

#Prints all the classes with all students who could attend said class
print("Monday 1", M1)
print("Monday 2", M2)
print("Tuesday 1", T1)
print("Tuesday 2", T2)

#Sorts through all classes and displays with start/delete
first_sort(M1, M2, T1, T2)
first_sort(M2, T1, T2, M1)
first_sort(T1, T2, M1, M2)
first_sort(T2, M1, M2, T1)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question @BogdanDoicin is in the post "I would like to not have to reinstate the print over and over. Not sure how to create a function for this process though because c1 through c4 change position with each if statement."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you want to "rotate" the c1 - c4 list, in respect wit the Monday/Tuesday strings.

this should do the trick:

```py
    days = ["Monday 1", "Monday 2", "Tuesday 1", "Tuesday 2"]
    cs_original = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
    m_and_ts = [M1, M2, T1, T2]

    c1_index_in_conditions = m_and_ts.index(c1)
    cs_rotated = cs_original[-c1_index_in_conditions:] + cs_original[:-c1_index_in_conditions]

    days_with_cs = zip(days, cs_rotated)

    print("\n")
    for day_w_c in days_with_cs:
        print(*day_w_c)

    counting(*cs_original)
```

the full solution with all your code:

```py
#All the students and their avalable days/times
students = ("Alec", "M1", "T1"), ("Ben", "M1", "M2", "T1"), ("Carl", "M1", "T1"), ("David", "M1", "M2", "T1"), ("Elvis", "M1", "M2", "T1", "T2"),\
           ("Fiona", "M1", "M2", "T1", "T2"), ("Gage", "M1", "M2", "T2"), ("Henry", "T1", "T2"), ("Isabel", "T2"), ("Jack", "T2")


#All classes
M1 = []
M2 = []
T1 = []
T2 = []

#Lessons the need for multiple lines of repeated code
def add_student(class_name, classes):
    if class_name in student:
        classes.append(student[0])

#Checks if class has minimum of 4 students
def counting(c1, c2, c3, c4):
        count = 0
        if len(c1) >= 4:
            count += len(c1)
        if len(c2) >= 4:
            count += len(c2)
        if len(c3) >= 4:
            count += len(c3)
        if len(c4) >= 4:
            count += len(c4)
        print("{:,}".format(count * 50000), "VND")


def first_sort(a, b, c, d):
    c1 = a.copy()
    c2 = b.copy()
    c3 = c.copy()
    c4 = d.copy()
    all_classes = (c1, c2, c3, c4)
    remove = []

    for student in students:
        for i in all_classes:
            if student[0] in remove:
                try:
                    i.remove(student[0])
                except:
                    pass
            elif student[0] in i:
                remove.append(student[0])

    days = ["Monday 1", "Monday 2", "Tuesday 1", "Tuesday 2"]
    cs_original = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
    m_and_ts = [M1, M2, T1, T2]

    c1_index_in_conditions = m_and_ts.index(c1)
    cs_rotated = cs_original[-c1_index_in_conditions:] + cs_original[:-c1_index_in_conditions]

    days_with_cs = zip(days, cs_rotated)

    print("\n")
    for day_w_c in days_with_cs:
        print(*day_w_c)

    counting(*cs_original)


#Checks if all the students are in a class then adds those who are into the class
for student in students:
    add_student("M1", M1)
    add_student("M2", M2)
    add_student("T1", T1)
    add_student("T2", T2)

#Prints all the classes with all students who could attend said class
print("Monday 1", M1)
print("Monday 2", M2)
print("Tuesday 1", T1)
print("Tuesday 2", T2)

#Sorts through all classes and displays with start/delete
first_sort(M1, M2, T1, T2)
first_sort(M2, T1, T2, M1)
first_sort(T1, T2, M1, M2)
first_sort(T2, M1, M2, T1)
```

basically it finds the position `c1` should be, and then pairs each `c*` with the corresponding string...

Comment: @HowardHughes does it work? does it print the right thing?

Comment: I have trouble understanding how this code does what it does and I'm sort of lost on how to produce the desired effect in my own code. Trying to make it work through brute force though. I can link the entire original code if you'd like.

Comment: 1) you should definitely edit the question with your complete code

Comment: 2) my code here is supposed to replace exactly the code you supplied, in the place it is right now.

Comment: @HowardHughes great, I ran your original code, then my version, and they both gave the same output. I just replace the `if... elif... elif...` code with my original answer

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I was dumb and spaced it incorrectly when I originaly replaced my code with yours. But now it works fine.